# too many arguments when attaching memory stream to email

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, stream, email-attachments

I have a database field varbinary which stores doc documents and pdf's.

I want to attach such a stream and email it. The email works fine without attachments.
I tried to test with a file (instead of retrieving the data from the database) but
I am stuck with 'Too many arguments to 'Public Sub New()'

Please help.

```
Dim fileName As String = "C:\Users\tzvei\Documents\test.pdf"
        ' Get the file stream . 
        ' Requires the System.IO namespace.
        Dim fs As New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
        ms.SetLength(fs.Length)
        fs.Read(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, CInt(fs.Length))

        m.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(ms, "test.pdf", "application/pdf")) 'here is the error Too many arguments

        ms.Flush()
        fs.Close()
        ms.Close()`
```

Comment: m variable is of what type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding an attachment to a .NET Email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570127/adding-an-attachment-to-a-net-email)

Comment: It is possible that another `Attachment` class is in scope (possibly your own). Ctor [`Attachment(Stream, String, String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment.attachment(v=vs.85).aspx) has been around since .Net 3.0, so it isn't that. Try `(New  System.Net.Mail.Attachment(...`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you StuartLC
this worked

```
   Dim fileName As String = "C:\Users\tzvei\Documents\ReferenceLetter.pdf"
    ' Get the file stream for the error log. 
    ' Requires the System.IO namespace.
    Dim fs As New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

    Dim mstream As New MemoryStream()
    mstream.SetLength(fs.Length)
    fs.Read(mstream.GetBuffer(), 0, CInt(fs.Length))
    Dim attach1 As New System.Net.Mail.Attachment(mstream, "blah", "application/pdf")

    m.Attachments.Add(attach1)
```